# PHP to execute form post at the end of the script / Checkout

Tags: php, curl

I cant get this done. 
Basically i have an html form that is posted to a php curl script that updates some contact fields on a CRM.

What i need to do is at the end of that php script i need to POST to the following checkout service, code below.

So basically the php script updates the custom fields and then execute the form post below to post that data to the checkout page.

Its part of a checkout funnel.

```
<form action="https://checkout.dineromail.com/CheckOut" method="post" > 
<!-- Variables     Obligatorias --> 
<input type="hidden" name="merchant" value="1721561" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="country_id" value="1" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="payment_method_available" value="all" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Ejemplo DVD" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_quantity_1" value="1" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_ammount_1" value="410" /> 

<!-- Boton --> 
<input type='image' src='https://argentina.dineromail.com/imagenes/botones/pagar-medios_c.gif' border='0' name='submit' alt='Pagar con DineroMail'> </form>
```

Did i explain myself clearly? In short: how to execute this form via post automatically at the end of the php script where this form resides on.

If anyone can help i'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
document.forms[0].submit();
})();
</script>
```

Try it

Comment: but before executing it i need to wait until the rest of the php curl script finished posting the values. So how can i execute ur js script AFTER eveyrthing else on the php script is done?

Comment: how could u translate the html from i pasted into curl?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use curl to post the data.  Instead of putting them into the HTML form, just take the values and forward them on to the next script:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://checkout.dineromail.com/CheckOut");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST)
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: but u are not stating the values to be post in your script there, would you mind adding the values that i posted on the html form so i can see how you do it?

Comment: because i only need to post the values that are on the html form not EVERY other value that is on that php page